QGIS - attribute table - column to mark last edit in row
I would like to know, if there is a way to create a column for a Layer, that automatically applies the date and time of the last edit/change of values in a row, if it occurs?

What data source is it, geopackage, PostgreSQL, ...? All edits are made in QGIS?

Setting now() as default value to a field and forcing the update of the field upon edit of the feature by using the checkbox should be what you're looking for. This can be done in the attribute form tab of the layer properties.

Note that this solution will only work for edit made in QGIS and will only work for project using the form setting (you may be able to define a default style for your data to make it work on all QGIS project)
